# How to edit price range in my magento catalog?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price, layered-navigation, navigation

I am working with magento 1.7.0.2 and I could change price range via admin : System > Configuration > Catalog (under Catalog) > Layered Navigation.

For example : range = 100, I have this :

```
100,00$ - 199,00$
200,00$ - 299,00$
300,00$ - 399,00$
400,00$ - 499,00$
```

I wish for example when I exceed the 500,00$ the range changed to 250 for example.

```
500,00$ - 749,00$
750,00$ - 999,00$
```

I searched how to do that and I found that I should edit this file : `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php` in getPriceRange() function but how to do that with different range like my example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php:164
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::getRangeItemCounts
foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
    ++$i;
    if ($calculation == self::RANGE_CALCULATION_MANUAL && $i > 1 && $i > $maxIntervalsNumber) {
        $items[$lastIndex] += $v;
        unset($items[$k]);
    } else {
        $lastIndex = $k;
    }
}
```

I don't know what this exactly does, but it is the part where the `RANGE_CALCULATION_MANUAL` is handled. So just hook into it with xdebug or something and check what `$items` is. I would think, that this array holds all the values which are later shown. So rewriting this block and just changing this method should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked the File /Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php
to deliver this functionality

This will destroy the dynamic price navigation site wide and replace it with these static price levels. Also this is not tested with anything other than simple products in one currency.
The code is quite messy and convoluted - but it works.

Replace this (line 161)

```
foreach ($dbRanges as $index=>$count) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel($range, $index),
                    'value' => $index . ',' . $range,
                    'count' => $count,
                );
            }
```

with this - edit the values as you need. Remember to refresh both the overall cache (cache>>refresh) and layered caches (refresh layered navigation) in cache management to see your changes.

```
///////// 0-5 ///////////////////////
                $count_first  = $this->getRangeItemCounts(5);
                $count_first_value = (array_key_exists(1, $count_first)) ? $count_first[1]:0;    
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(5, 1),
                    'value' => 1 . ',' . 5,
                    'count' => $count_first_value,
                );
    ///////// 5-7 ///////////////////////            
                $count_second  = $this->getRangeItemCounts(1);
                $count_second_value = 0;
                $count_second_value += 
                (array_key_exists(6, $count_second)) ? $count_second[6]:0;
                $count_second_value +=
                (array_key_exists(7, $count_second)) ? $count_second[7]:0;
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(2, 3.5),
                    'value' => 3.5 . ',' . 2,
                    'count' => $count_second_value,
                );

    ///////// 7-11 ///////////////////////            
                $count_third   = $this->getRangeItemCounts(1);
                $count_third_value = 0;
                $count_third_value += 
                (array_key_exists(8, $count_third)) ? $count_third[8]:0;
                $count_third_value += 
                (array_key_exists(9, $count_third)) ? $count_third[9]:0;
                $count_third_value += 
                (array_key_exists(10, $count_third)) ? $count_third[10]:0;
                $count_third_value += 
                (array_key_exists(11, $count_third)) ? $count_third[11]:0;                
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(4, 2.75),
                    'value' => 2.75 . ',' . 4,
                    'count' => $count_third_value,
                );

    ///////// 11-15 ///////////////////////
                $count_fourth   = $this->getRangeItemCounts(1);
                $count_fourth_value = 0;
                $count_fourth_value += 
                (array_key_exists(12, $count_fourth)) ? $count_fourth[12]:0;
                $count_fourth_value += 
                (array_key_exists(13, $count_fourth)) ? $count_fourth[13]:0;
                $count_fourth_value += 
                (array_key_exists(14, $count_fourth)) ? $count_fourth[14]:0;
                $count_fourth_value += 
                (array_key_exists(15, $count_fourth)) ? $count_fourth[15]:0;
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(4, 3.75),
                    'value' => 3.75 . ',' . 4,
                    'count' => $count_fourth_value,
                );

    ///////// 15-20 ///////////////////////            
                $count_fifth   = $this->getRangeItemCounts(5);
                $count_fifth_value = 0;
                $count_fifth_value += (array_key_exists(4, $count_fifth)) ? $count_fifth[4]:0;
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(5, 4),
                    'value' => 4 . ',' . 5,
                    'count' => $count_fifth_value,
                    );
```

There are obviously more for my page but you will get the idea. The if statements are there to stop Magento throwing errors when you don’t have any items in that price range. Some statements are easier than others - for example 15-20 only needs to count one range (the fourth index of range 5) whereas 11-15 is more complicated - I had to add 4 separate values ( the 12th - 15th index of range 1) - this is the only way I could think of to get the count working correctly.

You then may wish to add some logic to stop the range displaying if the count is 0 - not shown 
**explaination** 
there are two things you have to change.

First the label and link are changed by editing the following

```
'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(5, 1),
                    'value' => 1 . ',' . 5,
```

this means the first index of the range 5 (0-5). If you wanted to get items between 12-8 for example you would change to

```
‘label’ => $this->_renderItemLabel(6, 3),
‘value’ => 3. ‘,’ . 6,
```

The second (more complicated part) is to count the number of products in that range.

This is easy if you are only using whole numbers for your multiplier (the 1 or 3 in the above examples) In which case you would simply enter the variables into magento’s built in count function and it would give you the correct result.... ie

```
$count_first  = $this->getRangeItemCounts(5);
                $count_first_value = (array_key_exists(1, $count_first)) ? $count_first[1]:0;

translation:
1st line says --->> use the range of 5
2nd line says--> use only the first index in that range

if you wanted 6-18 you would change to
$count_first  = $this->getRangeItemCounts(6);
                $count_first_value = (array_key_exists(3, $count_first)) ? $count_first[3]:0;

If you want to use a multiple that is NOT a whole number then you need to concatenate multiple ranges… I will explain the following code
///////// 5-7 ///////////////////////            
                $count_second  = $this->getRangeItemCounts(1);
                $count_second_value = 0;
                $count_second_value += 
                (array_key_exists(6, $count_second)) ? $count_second[6]:0;
                $count_second_value +=
                (array_key_exists(7, $count_second)) ? $count_second[7]:0;
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel(2, 3.5),
                    'value' => 3.5 . ',' . 2,
                    'count' => $count_second_value,
                );
```

translation:
Use the range of one

then take to 6th and seventh indexes of that range and add them together (6th index is items in the range 5-6 and 7th index is items in the range 6-7).

You need to do it this way becasue:

```
$this->getRangeItemCounts()
```

only accepts whole numbers. If you try and use ca value with a decimal point (3.5) it will round it to the nearest whole number giving you the wrong output.

Good Luck, post your code if you’re still having trouble